# Problem with zabbix-fronend-php in maps after upgrade

Tags: devops, zabbix, web-frontend

I upgraded zabbix-frontend-php to last stable version (4.0.0) and get error in map.
In map i see only first element. In browser console i see next error:

```
TypeError: can't convert null to object jsLoader.php:2049:2
SVGElement.prototype.update http://zabbix.HOST/jsLoader.php:2049:2
SVGElement.prototype.create http://zabbix.HOST/jsLoader.php:2158:3
SVGElement http://zabbix.HOST/jsLoader.php:1980:3
SVGCanvas.prototype.createElement http://zabbix.HOST/jsLoader.php:1337:13
SVGTextArea.prototype.create http://zabbix.HOST/jsLoader.php:1753:17
SVGCanvas.prototype.createElement http://zabbix.HOST/jsLoader.php:1334:13
SVGElement.prototype.add http://zabbix.HOST/jsLoader.php:2015:16
SVGMapShape.prototype.update http://zabbix.HOST/jsLoader.php:3370:3
SVGMap.prototype.updateOrderedItems/< http://zabbix.HOST/jsLoader.php:2612:3
forEach self-hosted:268:13 SVGMap.prototype.updateOrderedItems http://zabbix.HOST/jsLoader.php:2607:2
SVGMap.prototype.update/< http://zabbix.HOST/jsLoader.php:2693:3
ImageCache.prototype.invokeCallback http://zabbixHOST/jsLoader.php:1847:3
ImageCache.prototype.handleCallback http://zabbix.HOST/jsLoader.php:1866:3
ImageCache.prototype.onImageLoaded http://zabbix.HOST/jsLoader.php:1878:2
ImageCache.prototype.preload/</image.onload http://zabbix.HOST/jsLoader.php:1935:4
```

I see this error at [Forum zabbix](https://www.zabbix.com/forum/zabbix-troubleshooting-and-problems/366919-problem-with-maps-after-upgrade-from-zabbix-3-4-to-4-0) , but it is not resolved.

Answer (score 0):

For temporary solve this problem, i'm downloaded last  zabbix-frontend-php from [git](https://github.com/zabbix/zabbix/tree/trunk/frontends/php) (from trunk, 1.0.14 version)  and was updated frontend. I'm not watching this error....